# Convert all strings in a list to integers

Tags: python, list, integer

How do I convert all strings in a list to integers?

```
['1', '2', '3']  ⟶  [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1505, accepted):

Given:

```
xs = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) then [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) to obtain a list of integers:

```
list(map(int, xs))
```

In Python 2, `list` was unnecessary since [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) returned a list:

```
map(int, xs)
```

Comment: I want to point out that pylint discourages the use of `map`, so prepare to use list comprehensions anyway if you ever use that standard. :)

Comment: The inverse is ( to convert a list of int to list of string ) :  map( str, results)

Comment: You can simplify this answer: just always use `list(map(int, results))`, it works for any Python version.

Comment: I just want to add for the map function its type is an iterable so technically if you were to iterate through it you wouldn't need to convert it into a list.

Answer (score 481):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) on the list `xs`:

```
[int(x) for x in xs]
```

e.g.

```
>>> xs = ["1", "2", "3"]
>>> [int(x) for x in xs]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: List comprehension is great too.  To the OP - see here for to see a nice contrast of map and list comprehension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Answer (score 11):

There are several methods to convert string numbers in a list to integers.

In Python 2.x you can use the [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
>>> results = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> results = map(int, results)
>>> results
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here, It returns the list of elements after applying the function.

In Python 3.x you can use the same [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> results = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> results = list(map(int, results))
>>> results
[1, 2, 3]
```

Unlike python 2.x, Here map function will return map object i.e. `iterator` which will yield the result(values) one by one that's the reason further we need to add a function named as `list` which will be applied to all the iterable items.

Refer to the image below for the return value of the `map` function and it's type in the case of python 3.x

[image: map function iterator object and it's type]

The third method which is common for both python 2.x and python 3.x i.e [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> results = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> results = [int(i) for i in results]
>>> results
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 8):

If your list contains pure integer strings, the accepted answer is the way to go. It will crash if you give it things that are not integers.

So: if you have data that may contain ints, possibly floats or other things as well - you can leverage your own function with errorhandling:

```
def maybeMakeNumber(s):
    """Returns a string 's' into a integer if possible, a float if needed or
    returns it as is."""

    # handle None, "", 0
    if not s:
        return s
    try:
        f = float(s)
        i = int(f)
        return i if f == i else f
    except ValueError:
        return s

data = ["unkind", "data", "42", 98, "47.11", "of mixed", "types"]

converted = list(map(maybeMakeNumber, data))
print(converted)
```

Output:

```
['unkind', 'data', 42, 98, 47.11, 'of mixed', 'types']
```

---

To also handle iterables inside iterables you can use this helper:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable, Mapping

def convertEr(iterab):
    """Tries to convert an iterable to list of floats, ints or the original thing
    from the iterable. Converts any iterable (tuple,set, ...) to itself in output.
    Does not work for Mappings  - you would need to check abc.Mapping and handle 
    things like {1:42, "1":84} when converting them - so they come out as is."""

    if isinstance(iterab, str):
        return maybeMakeNumber(iterab)

    if isinstance(iterab, Mapping):
        return iterab

    if isinstance(iterab, Iterable):
        return  iterab.__class__(convertEr(p) for p in iterab)


data = ["unkind", {1: 3,"1":42}, "data", "42", 98, "47.11", "of mixed", 
        ("0", "8", {"15", "things"}, "3.141"), "types"]

converted = convertEr(data)
print(converted)
```

Output:

```
['unkind', {1: 3, '1': 42}, 'data', 42, 98, 47.11, 'of mixed', 
 (0, 8, {'things', 15}, 3.141), 'types'] # sets are unordered, hence diffrent order
```

Answer (score 8):

You can easily convert string list items into int items using loop shorthand in python

Say you have a string `result = ['1','2','3']`

Just do,

```
result = [int(item) for item in result]
print(result)
```

It'll give you output like

```
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: The same solution has already been posted above.

Answer (score 5):

A little bit more expanded than list comprehension but likewise useful:

```
def str_list_to_int_list(str_list):
    n = 0
    while n < len(str_list):
        str_list[n] = int(str_list[n])
        n += 1
    return(str_list)
```

e.g.

```
>>> results = ["1", "2", "3"]
>>> str_list_to_int_list(results)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Also:

```
def str_list_to_int_list(str_list):
    int_list = [int(n) for n in str_list]
    return int_list
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simply in one line when taking input.

```
[int(i) for i in input().split("")]
```

Split it where you want.

If you want to convert a list not list simply put your list name in the place of `input().split("")`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution with explanation for your query.

```
 a=['1','2','3','4','5'] #The integer represented as a string in this list
 b=[] #Fresh list
 for i in a: #Declaring variable (i) as an item in the list (a).
     b.append(int(i)) #Look below for explanation
 print(b)
```

Here, **append()** is used to add items ( i.e integer version of string (i) in this program ) to the end of the list (b).

Note: **int()** is a function that helps to convert an integer in the form of string, back to its integer form.

**Output console:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So, we can convert the string items in the list to an integer only if the given string is entirely composed of numbers or else an error will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to add [Python | Converting all strings in list to integers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-converting-all-strings-in-list-to-integers/)

**Method #1 : Naive Method**

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate 
# converting list of strings to int 
# using naive method 

# initializing list 
test_list = ['1', '4', '3', '6', '7'] 

# Printing original list 
print ("Original list is : " + str(test_list)) 

# using naive method to 
# perform conversion 
for i in range(0, len(test_list)): 
    test_list[i] = int(test_list[i]) 
    

# Printing modified list 
print ("Modified list is : " + str(test_list))
```

**Output:**

```
Original list is : ['1', '4', '3', '6', '7']
Modified list is : [1, 4, 3, 6, 7]
```

**Method #2 : Using list comprehension**

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate 
# converting list of strings to int 
# using list comprehension 

# initializing list 
test_list = ['1', '4', '3', '6', '7'] 

# Printing original list 
print ("Original list is : " + str(test_list)) 

# using list comprehension to 
# perform conversion 
test_list = [int(i) for i in test_list] 
    

# Printing modified list 
print ("Modified list is : " + str(test_list))
```

**Output:**

```
Original list is : ['1', '4', '3', '6', '7']
Modified list is : [1, 4, 3, 6, 7]
```

**Method #3 : Using map()**

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate 
# converting list of strings to int 
# using map() 

# initializing list 
test_list = ['1', '4', '3', '6', '7'] 

# Printing original list 
print ("Original list is : " + str(test_list)) 

# using map() to 
# perform conversion 
test_list = list(map(int, test_list)) 
    

# Printing modified list 
print ("Modified list is : " + str(test_list))
```

**Output:**

```
Original list is : ['1', '4', '3', '6', '7']
Modified list is : [1, 4, 3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: You should consider adding performance metrics to the approaches you show. For example, which is faster: list comp or map? i.e. map

Comment: All of these methods were already thoroughly covered by existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

The answers below, even the most popular ones, do not work for all situations. I have such a solution for super resistant thrust str.
I had such a thing:

`AA = ['0', '0.5', '0.5', '0.1', '0.1', '0.1', '0.1']`

```
AA = pd.DataFrame(AA, dtype=np.float64)
AA = AA.values.flatten()
AA = list(AA.flatten())
AA
```

`[0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]`

You can laugh, but it works.

Comment: Well, yes; that's because *the problem you are solving is not the one that was asked about*. "Integer" has a specific meaning, and it does not include floating-point numbers. But even then, simply using `float` instead of `int` in any of the other approaches will work just fine for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

##### Coerce invalid input

`int()` raises an error if an invalid value is fed. If you want to set these invalid values to NaN and convert the valid values in the list (similar to how pandas' `to_numeric` behaves), you can do so using the following list comprehension:

```py
[int(x) if x.replace('-','', 1).replace('+','',1).isdecimal() else float('nan') for x in lst]
```

It is essentially checking if a value is decimal or not (either negative or positive). Scientific notation (e.g. `1e3`) can also be a valid integer, in that case, we can add another condition to the comprehension (albeit less legible):

```py
[int(x) if x.replace('-','', 1).replace('+','',1).isdecimal() else int(e[0])*10**int(e[1]) if (e:=x.split('e',1))[1:] and e[1].isdecimal() else float('nan') for x in lst]
```

For `lst = ['+1', '2', '-3', 'string', '4e3']`, the above comprehension returns `[1, 2, -3, nan, 4000]`. With minor adjustments, we can make it handle floats too but that's a separate topic.

##### map() is faster than list comprehension

`map()` is about 64% faster than the list comprehension. As can be seen from the following performance plot, `map()` outperforms list comprehension regardless of list size.

[image: res]

The code used to produce the plot:

```py
from random import choices, randint
from string import digits
from perfplot import plot
plot(
    setup=lambda n: [''.join(choices(digits, k=randint(1,10))) for _ in range(n)],
    kernels=[lambda lst: [int(x) for x in lst], lambda lst: list(map(int, lst))],
    labels= ["[int(x) for x in lst]", "list(map(int, lst))"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(4, 22)],
    xlabel='Number of items',
    title='Converting strings to integers',
    equality_check=lambda x,y: x==y);
```