# Python - Convert partial sublist's elements into int

Tags: python, list, int, partial, sublist

Suppose you have a list like:

```
[["a", "1", "2", "3"], ["b", "4", "5", "6"], ["c", "7", "8", "9"]]
```

And I want to convert the elements from index 1 to 2 of every sublist into integers as you can see they are themselves strings. Is it possible? If it is, then what is the shortest way to do it? What have I done uptil now is this:

```
lists = [["a", "1", "2", "3"], ["b", "4", "5", "6"], ["c", "7", "8", "9"]]
for l in lists:
    l[1:4] = [int(x) for x in l[1:4]]
print(lists)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert all strings in a list to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: @Torxed no it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Just keep in mind that having a multi-type list (i.e. a list with more than one type of variables) is considered a bad practice and it would not work in many other programming languages :) Cheers, Alex

Comment: @mbatchkarov: the obvious thing wrong with the questioner's code is that they say they want to convert elements 1 to 2, but the code actually converts elements 1 to 3 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert the lists inplace, your code is good enough.

BTW, the list comprehension can be replaced with `map`:

```
l[1:4] = map(int, l[1:4])
```

Comment: Haha, i was 5 seconds to late :) +1