# How can i format my list to give it as input to svm.train() in opencv3.0

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, svm

I am using opencv3.0,My IDE is pycharm

I have two lists one list of training_set and one list of trainig_labels.
training_set is a list of lists like

```
[array([119, 122,  91, ..., 185,  80, 255], dtype=uint8), array([112, 106,   120, ..., 121, 138, 255], dtype=uint8), ....... ]
```

training_labels is list of labels for each list in training_set.training_labels looks like

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

But when i try to pass this to svm.train()

```
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()

trainingdata =  map(int, training_set)
responses = map(int, training_labels)

svm.train(trainingdata,responses,params=svm_params)
svm.save('svm_data.dat')
```

I am getting this error

```
trainingdata =  map(int, training_set)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How to format my data correctly before giving it as input to svm.train()

Comment: What do you expect to get after `map(int, training_set)`?
For now you are trying to call `int` on `array([119, ...,  255], dtype=uint8)`.
Of course it is wrong.

Comment: @AleksandrKovalev i am expecting that the list will be converted to int.What is the right method?i googled and i ended up in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int

Comment: You have list of arrays. What do you want to get after conversion? Plain list of integers? Or list of lists of integers?

Comment: And btw, do you use python2 or python3?

Comment: @AleksandrKovalev I want trainining_set=list of lists,training_label=label of each list in training_set.when i directly give this svm.train(training_set,cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,training_labels) i am getting error:TypeError: samples is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: @AleksandrKovalev python 2.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106833/discussion-between-emmanu-varghese-and-aleksandr-kovalev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly i got the answer.I switched to opencv2.4.I modifed my code as

```
trainData=np.float32(training_set)
responses=np.float32(training_labels)
svm = cv2.SVM()
svm.train(trainData,responses, params=svm_params)
svm.save('svm_data.dat')
```

Now every thing is perfect.