# OpenCV3 Python, svm.train() TypeError

Tags: python, svm, opencv3.0

When I use Opencv3 with Python2, my code is to do something with SVM.

But an Error is shown:

> svm.train(trainData,responses,params = svm_params) TypeError: only
>   length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because the function was expecting a single array object and `trainData` variable contained multiple array objects. There are several ways to solve this, one of them is, say if your input object is:

```
# Used for creating training samples for a logic gate (eg: xor) NN
trainData = np.random.randint(2,size=2)
# array([ ..some values.. ])
```

then add [np.newaxis] to it

```
np.random.randint(2,size=2)[np.newaxis]
# array([[ ..some values.. ]])
```

See: [numpy newaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385666/numpy-use-reshape-or-newaxis-to-add-dimensions), [numpy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: Tanks for your reply. But my trainData is got like this:
    deskewed = [map(deskew,row) for row in train_cells]
    hogdata = [map(hog,row) for row in deskewed]
    trainData = np.float32(hogdata).reshape(-1,64)
    responses = np.float32(np.repeat(np.arange(10),250)[:,np.newaxis])
The problem is still exit. Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Here is another answer which may be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110924/how-can-i-format-my-list-to-give-it-as-input-to-svm-train-in-opencv3-0