# iterating through a user defined list with arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

```
taxNo = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
thisMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
myDF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(thisMap)[0]
myLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(myDF)
for lyr in myLayers:
if lyr.name == "Address Numbers":
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,"NEW_SELECTION","EKEY = " + taxNo[0])
    for tax in taxNo:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,"ADD_TO_SELECTION","EKEY = " + tax)
        arcpy.AddWarning("Additional Selection " + tax)
```

I'm trying to build a script in ArcGIS that will select a series of user defined values, in this case I'm trying to select 1784102 and 1784110.  When I use arcpy.AddWarning(taxNo) before the loop, I get the output "1784102;1784110" but it's iterating through it one number at a time i.e.

Additional Selection 1

Additional Selection 7

Additional Selection 8

Additional Selection 4
etc.

then pops up an error when it hits the semi-colon.
The parameters for taxNo are set up in ArcMap as a String, Multivalue, Valuelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just assume you are calling your script like this:

```
python script.py 1784102;1784110
```

Your variable `taxNo = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` then is a single string `"1784102;1784110"`. If you use "array indexes" on strings (for example `taxNo[0]`, `taxNo[1]` etc.) you are getting single characters out of that string, i.e. "1", "7", "8" ...

Call `.split(';')` to your `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` result to split the string `"1784102;1784110"` into an array of two strings: `["1784102", "1784110"]`. If you need a numeric item, i.e. integers, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int) too.

```
taxNo = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0).split(';')
```