# Iterating over the index or entry? How to iterate on index?

Tags: python, list, integer

Hello I am really new to learning python, and I am getting confused working with lists.

I wrote the following and I get the following

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

My code is:

```
numlist = list()
listy = ['341', '22', '1803']
for i in listy:
    numlist = int(listy[i])
```

So in this program I am trying to write, part of it includes a list of numbers. I want to take those numbers and append them to another list (numlist) that converts each entry in the first list to an integer type.

So I thought I needed to step through each entry in listy. 
Does the problem stem from 'i' referencing the entry (ex: '341' and not index 0)? If so...how do you refer to the index? I thought that's what I was doing, but clearly not :(.

Any help would be much appreciated. I looked through some other questions posted to Stack with the same Type Error but I'm so new to this that they all just confused me further.

Comment: Not saying this is a clever approach ;-) but try `numlist = int(listy[int(i)])` as the i is a string and you need it as index number, thus add `int(i)`instead of just `i` inside ? Also numlist will always be replaced with next iteration ...

Comment: You should be using `list.append()` to add an element to the list. For adding all the element of one list to another, you may use `list.extend()`

Comment: `numlist = list()`
`listy = ['341', '22', '1803']`
`for i in listy:`
      `numlist.append(int(i))`

Comment: And yes,  'i' is referencing the entry (ex: '341' and not index 0). For accessing the index, you should be iterating using range as `for i in range(len(listy))`

Comment: @Moinuddin Thank you for clarifying about the index, helps me understand the error! Also if I want to change each element to integer type is it most efficient to try to do that within the extend? Ex: numlist.extend(int(listy[i]) if that makes sense? Or better to write separate line of code to accomplish that?

Comment: @mcrocker take a look at: [Convert all strings in a list to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: Thank you for the links, I am learning about how to pose better questions and search for duplicates in stack overflow as a result! & Thanks for the suggested approaches :)