# Splitting list in list and converting list into an integer list

Tags: python

I am trying to spilt the following list so that I can use it for further purposes: 
How to split ['1,1','2,2'] into [1,1,2,2] in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert all strings in a list to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: split? This is simply `[int(x) for x in thelist]`...

Comment: It would be useful if you show what code you have tried so we can help build up your knowledge.

Comment: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[int(i) for i in item.split(',')] for item in lst]))`

Comment: Don't use this one: `eval(str(lst).replace("'",""))`

Comment: @abcd if any of the answers helped you, mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

This list comprehension would work -

```
s = ['1, 1', '2, 2']
print [int(j) for i in s for j in i.split(',')]
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: I believe this would be the fastest out of all current answers

Answer (score 0):

Join the list on `','` and then split it back up and map to integers:

```
>>> l = ['1,1', '2,2']
>>> list(map(int, ','.join(l).split(',')))
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```