# Fast method of converting all strings in a list to integers

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, type-conversion

I've gone through the [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int) post

I want to convert

```
results = ['1', '2', '3']
```

to:

```
results = [1, 2, 3]
```

I know i can do it by

> 1. map(int, results)

and

> 2. results = list(map(int, results))

I want it faster way may be using numpy or more faster.

Actual code is

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
import numpy as np
n = int(stdin.readline())


for i in range(0,n):
    lone = 0
    m = int(stdin.readline())
    results = stdin.readline().split()
    o = np.array(results, dtype=np.int64)
    for j in range (0,m):
        if o[j] in  o[j+1:m]:
            lone = lone +1
        elif o[j] in o [0:j]:
            lone = lone +1
        else:
            stdout.write(str(o[j]) + '\n')

    if lone == m:
        stdout.write ("-1 \n")
```

Please let me know if there is any methods to achieve this when trying to work with thousands of strings

Comment: What is so slow with the method you have above?

Comment: when I am working on more than few thousand numbers it takes more than 6-7 seconds just to convert those numbers into integers @BurhanKhalid

Comment: Are you sure this is the part taking the time? 6 - 7 seconds is a GIANT amount of time for a simple conversion operation. This sounds like you have an issue somewhere else. Can you post your timing code?

Comment: Please check the edits @BurhanKhalid

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiprocessing is a way to get it done faster (in addition of using Numpy):

E.g:

```
In [11]: from multiprocessing import Pool

In [12]: pool = Pool(10)

In [13]: pool.map(int, [str(i) for i in range(500)])
```

Numpy will mostly provide a memory gain as you would be dealing with primitive types instead of python objects, but will also provide a non-negligible speed gain as well.
Optimizing time of an iteration like this is always done by using parallelization so I advise using both Numpy and a process pool.

Comment: No way is this going to be faster than anything numpy, unless you probably combine numpy with this somehow, and even then you'll only see differences over 1M elements, possibly more. Multiprocessing simply presents too much overhead to be useful here.

Comment: I'm not saying that Python objects will be faster that numpy primitives. I'm saying that iterations are best optimized with parallelization. Best to use both anyway. And for a very very long list the pool will win for sure. I'll edit to reflect that thought.