# How to convert the strings in sublists into integer faster without forloop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert the strings in sublists into integer.
Here is the code,

**Example Input:**

```
totalclient=[['5', '110'], ['9', '500'], ['20', '400']]
totalhouse=[['10', '100'], ['2', '200'], ['30', '300']]
```

This example list has only 4 sublists, But I want to process over 700 sublists for two lists and every sublist will have more than 300 strings!

**Code:**

```
totalclient = [list(map(int, sublist)) for sublist in totalclient]
totalhouse = [list(map(int, sublist)) for sublist in totalhouse]
```

**Output**

```
[[5, 110], [9, 500], [20, 400]]
[[10, 100], [2, 200], [30, 300]]
```

Above code works for me! But **for loop** takes too much time to convert it is there any other way to convert it into integer **without using for loop**?

I tried to convert sublist while inputting sublists like belowcode but it also takes same time!

```
for i in range(0,n[0]):
    client=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    totalclient.append(client)
```

Comment: You have a use a *for* somewhere, even if you're not typing `for ...` explicitly. Except of course, you want to manually remove the quotes yourself, then no need for *for*.

Comment: What you are saying please say clearly

Comment: The above commenter is right, but it might be faster to do it in place? Loop over it and explicitly change each one rather than creating a new list. It's still a for loop, but you avoid needing to create extra space in memory.

Comment: You guys saying to put like this right?                                                          
for i in range(0,n[0]):
    client=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    totalclient.append(client)

Comment: @AzizStark Your code is fine. Some tasks simply take some time. And how much time are we talking about here? It does not feel like this should be more than a few seconds if even..

Comment: Don't you have to iterate through your sublist object before applying it to `map` to convert it into integer? I believe you have not posted the complete code?

Comment: I edited the question see it

Comment: Yes, i didnot posted the complete code because it is a part of my Bipartite matching Script!

Comment: In the end, you still have to convert all the strings to integers. It does not matter how you loop over the collection, there are no shortcuts, unfortunately.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46341628/7692463

Comment: This code converts the list elements into strings without for loop!                 n = list(map(int, n))

Comment: but for only lists without sublists

Comment: list() is a for loop. It loops over the stuff in the brackets.

Comment: `n = list(map(int, n))` is essentially identical to `n = [int(item) for item in n]`. The fact that you didn't write `for`, does not mean that a for loop doesn't exist.

Comment: Try collecting your input as integers to begin with, if you really are that concerned about it

Comment: @cricket_007 As i said that also makes use of for loop and takes same time.

Comment: Can anyone optimize my entire code if I send you?

Comment: For loop where? No loops are needed for `totalclient=[[5, 110]]`... You're focusing too much on the implementation than benchmarking where the actual bottleneck of the code is

Comment: If you'd like someone to review your working code, please see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Here is my entire code : http://textuploader.com/d4uzo                                                         Could any one help me?

Comment: I used pypy3 instead of python it worked 3 times faster than python3!! Python 3 needs to be improved!

Comment: @scharette thanks for the help! that post helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem ! Glad it helped

Comment: Sad that people that people don't upvote the comment though because there will be no accepted/useful answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was faster on my machine:

```
tc = np.array(list(repeat(['1000000000000000','200000000000'], 700)))
tl = np.array(list(repeat(['2000000000000000','300000000000'], 700)))

def s1(tc,tl):
    totalc = [list(map(int, sublist)) for sublist in tc]
    totalh = [list(map(int, sublist)) for sublist in tl]

def s2(tc,tl):
    ntc = list(map(lambda w: [map(int, w)], chain(tc)))
    ntc = list(map(lambda w: [map(int, w)], chain(tl)))

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

wrp1 = wrapper(s1, tc, tl)
wrp2 = wrapper(s2, tc, tl)
print(timeit.timeit(wrp1, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(wrp2, number=1000))

>>> wrp1 = 5.529523203999929
>>> wrp2 = 0.8688932149999573
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this,

```
from functools import *
totalclient=[['5', '110'], ['9', '500'], ['20', '400']]
totalhouse=[['10', '100'], ['2', '200'], ['30', '300']]
a1 = []
a2 = []
for i in totalclient:
    aa = map((lambda x:int(x)),i)
    a1.append(list(aa))
totalclient = a1
for i in totalhouse:
    aa = map((lambda x:int(x)),i)
    a2.append(list(aa))
totalhouse = a2

print(totalclient)
print(totalhouse)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! but it takes extra time than before!