# How to convert numpy array elements from string to int

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of numbers in string format. I converted that list into numpy array using `np.asarray()`.

How do I convert the string elements to ints?

Comment: [`np.asarray(listx, dtype = int)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)? Given that the strings are integers.

Comment: It seems to be working, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: @zipa I have tried 'map' to convert but it's completing my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `x = np.matrix`, where each element is '1.0' (as `str`) and you want to convert it to `int` or `float`:

```
x = x.astype(np.float)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
nums_str = ['1','23','345']
nums_str_np = np.asarray(nums_str)
nums_int_np = nums_str_np.astype('int')
```

`nums_int_np` - is now np array of integers.