# How to remove row containing array of NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a df like this:

```
   num1    num2
0  [2.0]   10
1  [3.0]   20
2  [4.0]   30
3  [5.0]   40
4  [6.0]   50
5  [nan]   60 
6  [nan]   70
7  [10.0]  80
8  [nan]   90
9  [15.0]  100
```

`num1` column contains arrays of floats. `[nan]` is a numpy array containing a single `np.NaN`.

I am converting this to integers via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int):

```
df['num1'] = list(map(int, df['num1']))
```

If I just use this df:

```
   num1    num2
0  [2.0]   10
1  [3.0]   20
2  [4.0]   30
3  [5.0]   40
4  [6.0]   50
```

This works when there are no `[nan]` and I get:

```
   num1   num2
0  2.0  10
1  3.0  20
2  4.0  30
3  5.0  40
4  6.0  50
```

But if I include the full df with `[nan]` I get the error:

```
`ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`
```

I tried doing:

```
df[df['num1'] != np.array(np.NaN)]
```

But this gave the error:

```
TypeError: len() of unsigned object
```

How can I get the desired output:

```
   num1    num2
0  2.0   10
1  3.0   20
2  4.0   30
3  5.0   40
4  6.0   50
5  10.0  80
6  15.0  100
```

Comment: have you tried this : `df = df[np.isfinite(df['EPS'])]`

Comment: @fabianegli Where in the duplicate does it say how to remove a value in a df which is equal to an array...?

Comment: what is the data type of emement in columns 1?? list of int or obejct??

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi list of floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
df['num1'] = df['num1'].apply(lambda x: x[0]).dropna() # unlist the list of numbers (assuming you dont have multiple)
df['num1'] = list(map(int, df['num1'])) # map operation
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   num1  num2
0     2    10
1     3    20
2     4    30
3     5    40
4     6    50
7    10    80
9    15   100
```

**Timings (depends on size of data)**

```
# My solution
# 2.6 ms ± 327 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @O.Suleiman's solution
# 2.8 ms ± 457 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @ Anton vBR's solution
# 2.96 ms ± 504 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just updated my output (I had not removed the list following the `map`). So your answer is still valid, just don't need the last line to convert back to list.

Comment: @fabianegli Worked for me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ (For me the `drop na` is on a separate line as `df = df.dropna(subset='num1')`.

Comment: @Chuck My issue is the fact that you have to change the code to make it work. The way it is now raises a ValueError. If this solution is edited to contain the actual code that works, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

This should get rid of all those `nan` lists, just add the following:

```
df = df.loc[df['num1'].str[0].dropna().index]
```

Then you can run the rest of your code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['num1'] = df.num1.str[0]
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

A solution inspired by [suleiman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48928335/4683950) answer but without using loc 
And here is the output :

```
num1    num2
0   2.0 10
1   3.0 20
2   4.0 30
3   5.0 40
4   6.0 50
7   10.0    80
9   15.0    100
```

Comment: the first code doesn't seem to produce the output the OP wants

Comment: This code will also remove rows that have np.NaN in any other column than num1.

Comment: thanks for the feedback , and the review , I didin't think about that , but it solved this particular problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
# convert np array containing NaNs into np.NaN
df['num1']=df['num1'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if np.nan in x else x[0])

# use dropna to drop the rows
df=df['num1'].dropna()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   num1    num2
0  2.0   10
1  3.0   20
2  4.0   30
3  5.0   40
4  6.0   50
5  10.0  80
6  15.0  100
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are many options. You can convert to numeric and then remove nulls:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = dict(num1=[[2.0],[np.nan],['apple']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

m = pd.to_numeric(df['num1'].apply(lambda x: x[0]),errors='coerce').dropna().index

df = df.loc[m]
```