# Changing one element in a list from string to integer

Tags: python, string, list, int

I was looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int), but I don't have the privilege to add a comment.

My question is:

```
> results = [int(i) for i in results]

>>> results = ["1", "2", "3"]

>>> results = [int(i) for i in results]

>>> results

[1, 2, 3]
```

What if I need to change only the first element in the list, how can I do that?
By indexing? so something like:

```
> results=[int(1) for i in results]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply write:

```
results[1] = int(results[1])
```

To change first element:

```
results[0] = int(results[0]) #because of 0 based indexing
```

Generally :

```
results[index] = int(results[index])
```

Comment: It said i can accept the answer in 7 minutes. im just waiting for those 7 minutes

Comment: Accepted! Thanks!