# How to append multiple integers to a list as a list from one input?

Tags: python, integer, append, extend

How do i receive multiple numbers from one input as a list of integers, then add this list to another list? To better explain, here's my last attempt:

```
list = []

for z in range (0, int(input())):
    list.append(input().split()) 

print(list[0])
print(list[1])
print(list)
```

with the inputs:

```
2
1 2
5 8
```

I get the following outputs:

```
['1', '2']
['5', '8']
[['1', '2'], ['5', '8']]
```

Now, what I’m looking for, is to receive those inputs somehow as integers, so the output for the same inputs would be:

```
[1, 2]
[5, 8]
[[1, 2], [5, 8]]
```

Thanks in advance for taking your time to help. I have tried to find the solution in the forum, but failed. Sorry if this has already been asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user). Third google result for searching *python input list of integer* BTW...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to convert the elements of the lists:

```
for z in range (0, int(input())):
    list.append([int(i) for i in input().split()])
```