# Converting a list of strings to integers

Tags: python

I'm working on a project and one of the requirements that is needed for it requires me to convert the set of temperatures from the data but I can't figure out how to start it. I need to get it in Fahrenheit but my problem is that the data are strings inside a list of a list and I can't figure out how to convert that into an integer so I can change it into Fahrenheit.

**All of the listed temperatures in the data are in Celsius.**

Here's what I have so far.

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

link = "https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/tabledata_v3/GLB.Ts+dSST.txt"
f = requests.get(link)
data = f.text
lines = data.split('\n')


el = []                    # creates an empty list
for each in lines[8:159]:  # gets rid of unnecessary information. Prints from 1880 to 2018
    tempL = each.split()
    if (tempL and tempL[0] != 'Year'):    # gets rid of the excess data like the title
        el.append(tempL[:13])
```

My result so far looks like this...

```
[['1880', '-29', '-18', '-11', '-20', '-12', '-23', '-21', '-9', '-16', '-23', '-20', '-23'], ['1881', '-16', '-17', '4', '4', '2', '-20', '-7', '-3', '-14', '-21', '-22', '-11'], ['1882', '14', '15', '3', '-19', '-16', '-26', '-21', '-6', '-10', '-25', '-16', '-25'], ['1883', '-32', '-39', '-13', '-17', '-20', '-13', '-8', '-15', '-21', '-14', '-22', '-16'], ['1884', '-16', '-8', '-37', '-43', '-37', '-41', '-35', '-26', '-27', '-24', '-30', '-29'], ['1885', '-59', '-30', '-25', '-42', '-42', '-44', '-36', '-32', '-24', '-19', '-20', '-5'], ['1886', '-42', '-45', '-39', '-28', '-26', '-39', '-22', '-34', '-26', '-29', '-31', '-27'], ['1887', '-73', '-52', '-34', '-39', '-32', '-24', '-23', '-32', '-23', '-33', '-23', '-34'], ['1888', '-38', '-36', '-41', '-22', '-22', '-18', '-9', '-16', '-10', '2', '1', '-6'], ['1889', '-11', '19', '8', '7', '-2', '-14', '-10', '-20', '-22', '-22', '-33', '-30'], ['1890', '-44', '-45', '-40', '-37', '-45', '-27', '-27', '-38', '-39', '-24', '-48', '-31'], ['1891', '-42', '-47', '-19', '-28', '-18', '-20', '-20', '-16', '-14', '-21', '-35', '-4'], ['1892', '-28', '-12', '-35', '-35', '-25', '-23', '-32', '-25', '-13', '-13', '-42', '-39'], ['1893', '-80', '-54', '-23', '-30', '-36', '-29', '-16', '-27', '-20', '-17', '-17', '-35'], ['1894', '-54', '-33', '-25', '-48', '-35', '-44', '-26', '-22', '-25', '-21', '-25', '-20'], ['1895', '-44', '-42', '-29', '-25', '-27', '-24', '-18', '-16', '-9', '-8', '-15', '-16'], ['1896', '-26', '-14', '-26', '-31', '-18', '-14', '-4', '-4', '-3', '11', '-8', '-4'], ['1897', '-15', '-15', '-14', '-2', '-5', '-16', '-7', '-11', '-8', '-12', '-19', '-19'], ['1898', '-3', '-30', '-52', '-33', '-32', '-21', '-24', '-25', '-22', '-33', '-38', '-25'], ['1899', '-19', '-40', '-34', '-21', '-23', '-33', '-18', '-7', '-3', '-5', '12', '-28'], ['1900', '-37', '-3', '1', '-12', '-10', '-13', '-13', '-10', '-5', '9', '-10', '-7'], ['1901', '-24', '-4', '8', '-4', '-17', '-13', '-16', '-20', '-22', '-31', '-17', '-28'], ['1902', '-20', '-3', '-29', '-30', '-35', '-35', '-30', '-32', '-29', '-29', '-39', '-46'], ['1903', '-26', '-4', '-24', '-43', '-44', '-46', '-37', '-49', '-49', '-48', '-45', '-52'], ['1904', '-68', '-58', '-51', '-55', '-56', '-51', '-54', '-50', '-53', '-40', '-22', '-35'], ['1905', '-40', '-59', '-24', '-36', '-33', '-31', '-29', '-22', '-19', '-25', '-10', '-19'], ['1906', '-28', '-31', '-16', '-4', '-24', '-21', '-25', '-20', '-27', '-19', '-39', '-16'], ['1907', '-42', '-51', '-27', '-39', '-47', '-44', '-37', '-35', '-33', '-24', '-49', '-48'], ['1908', '-44', '-31', '-54', '-46', '-41', '-41', '-40', '-46', '-36', '-45', '-50', '-49'], ['1909', '-69', '-47', '-51', '-60', '-56', '-53', '-45', '-31', '-35', '-37', '-31', '-55'], ['1910', '-45', '-44', '-51', '-40', '-35', '-38', '-35', '-37', '-36', '-38', '-54', '-66'], ['1911', '-64', '-58', '-60', '-54', '-52', '-48', '-41', '-42', '-38', '-23', '-18', '-22'], ['1912', '-26', '-12', '-35', '-20', '-22', '-26', '-44', '-55', '-51', '-57', '-38', '-43'], ['1913', '-42', '-43', '-43', '-40', '-47', '-49', '-37', '-34', '-36', '-34', '-19', '-4'], ['1914', '4', '-11', '-22', '-29', '-23', '-26', '-24', '-14', '-13', '-4', '-18', '-8'], ['1915', '-17', '0', '-10', '6', '-7', '-21', '-11', '-20', '-17', '-25', '-13', '-17'], ['1916', '-9', '-13', '-28', '-30', '-32', '-47', '-36', '-26', '-32', '-27', '-40', '-80'], ['1917', '-58', '-61', '-60', '-51', '-55', '-43', '-25', '-22', '-18', '-40', '-28', '-68'], ['1918', '-42', '-32', '-25', '-45', '-46', '-36', '-31', '-30', '-15', '-5', '-11', '-28'], ['1919', '-20', '-23', '-20', '-14', '-28', '-38', '-29', '-33', '-22', '-19', '-41', '-42'], ['1920', '-23', '-23', '-8', '-26', '-27', '-36', '-32', '-25', '-20', '-27', '-27', '-44'], ['1921', '-3', '-19', '-23', '-29', '-29', '-28', '-15', '-24', '-17', '-3', '-13', '-17'], ['1922', '-34', '-44', '-13', '-24', '-33', '-33', '-25', '-31', '-32', '-32', '-14', '-18'], ['1923', '-29', '-37', '-35', '-40', '-34', '-26', '-30', '-30', '-28', '-11', '1', '-2'], ['1924', '-22', '-24', '-7', '-31', '-18', '-23', '-26', '-34', '-31', '-34', '-20', '-41'], ['1925', '-36', '-38', '-25', '-25', '-30', '-32', '-28', '-15', '-16', '-18', '4', '9'], ['1926', '19', '6', '11', '-13', '-22', '-23', '-24', '-13', '-13', '-10', '-5', '-28'], ['1927', '-27', '-18', '-37', '-31', '-25', '-26', '-16', '-21', '-11', '-1', '-4', '-33'], ['1928', '-1', '-8', '-27', '-28', '-30', '-37', '-19', '-23', '-19', '-17', '-9', '-18'], ['1929', '-46', '-60', '-32', '-40', '-39', '-41', '-33', '-29', '-23', '-12', '-12', '-54'], ['1930', '-30', '-27', '-9', '-24', '-23', '-20', '-20', '-12', '-12', '-9', '15', '-8'], ['1931', '-10', '-24', '-8', '-21', '-20', '-7', '-3', '-3', '-6', '2', '-12', '-9'], ['1932', '14', '-18', '-19', '-6', '-18', '-29', '-24', '-23', '-12', '-10', '-27', '-26'], ['1933', '-34', '-34', '-30', '-25', '-29', '-33', '-21', '-24', '-27', '-21', '-30', '-46'], ['1934', '-24', '-4', '-33', '-30', '-11', '-15', '-10', '-11', '-16', '-8', '3', '-4'], ['1935', '-33', '15', '-13', '-36', '-30', '-27', '-22', '-22', '-21', '-8', '-28', '-20'], ['1936', '-28', '-39', '-22', '-20', '-18', '-21', '-8', '-13', '-9', '-4', '-4', '-3'], ['1937', '-13', '4', '-18', '-17', '-8', '-5', '-5', '2', '11', '8', '9', '-11'], ['1938', '1', '-2', '8', '4', '-10', '-18', '-9', '-6', '2', '11', '4', '-22'], ['1939', '-7', '-8', '-19', '-9', '-6', '-8', '-8', '-7', '-7', '-3', '6', '44'], ['1940', '-6', '13', '15', '18', '10', '8', '12', '5', '13', '8', '17', '28'], ['1941', '21', '32', '8', '17', '14', '12', '21', '14', '2', '34', '24', '21'], ['1942', '26', '2', '9', '11', '9', '4', '0', '-4', '-5', '-1', '8', '7'], ['1943', '-4', '13', '-8', '7', '4', '-6', '8', '0', '6', '22', '19', '24'], ['1944', '35', '26', '27', '20', '19', '20', '18', '17', '30', '26', '10', '2'], ['1945', '9', '-2', '7', '18', '5', '-1', '3', '27', '22', '19', '7', '-9'], ['1946', '15', '7', '1', '6', '-8', '-21', '-14', '-16', '-7', '-6', '-6', '-35'], ['1947', '-13', '-8', '7', '7', '-3', '2', '-8', '-9', '-13', '6', '2', '-16'], ['1948', '7', '-15', '-25', '-11', '1', '-4', '-11', '-12', '-11', '-7', '-12', '-23'], ['1949', '9', '-16', '-2', '-10', '-8', '-23', '-14', '-12', '-14', '-6', '-10', '-22'], ['1950', '-33', '-28', '-7', '-20', '-9', '-3', '-10', '-16', '-12', '-22', '-38', '-20'], ['1951', '-35', '-43', '-21', '-13', '0', '-2', '3', '6', '8', '5', '-2', '14'], ['1952', '13', '11', '-10', '2', '-2', '-4', '4', '4', '7', '-1', '-14', '-1'], ['1953', '8', '14', '11', '18', '9', '10', '0', '6', '4', '6', '-6', '2'], ['1954', '-28', '-13', '-15', '-17', '-21', '-17', '-19', '-17', '-10', '-4', '6', '-22'], ['1955', '14', '-17', '-34', '-21', '-21', '-12', '-12', '1', '-11', '-5', '-24', '-30'], ['1956', '-16', '-26', '-23', '-27', '-31', '-16', '-12', '-26', '-20', '-24', '-17', '-8'], ['1957', '-11', '-4', '-6', '-1', '9', '16', '1', '15', '9', '1', '6', '16'], ['1958', '39', '24', '11', '3', '7', '-7', '5', '-3', '-2', '4', '2', '0'], ['1959', '8', '9', '18', '13', '4', '2', '6', '-1', '-6', '-9', '-9', '-1'], ['1960', '-1', '16', '-34', '-14', '-7', '-4', '-3', '1', '7', '7', '-12', '18'], ['1961', '7', '19', '9', '12', '11', '11', '0', '3', '7', '0', '3', '-15'], ['1962', '7', '14', '12', '4', '-4', '4', '2', '-1', '1', '0', '7', '0'], ['1963', '-2', '20', '-14', '-6', '-4', '5', '8', '27', '20', '15', '15', '-1'], ['1964', '-8', '-13', '-23', '-31', '-25', '-2', '-3', '-21', '-29', '-31', '-21', '-30'], ['1965', '-8', '-17', '-11', '-19', '-14', '-9', '-12', '-3', '-16', '-5', '-7', '-6'], ['1966', '-17', '-1', '5', '-12', '-11', '1', '9', '-8', '-2', '-15', '-2', '-6'], ['1967', '-6', '-21', '4', '-5', '14', '-8', '1', '1', '-6', '8', '-7', '-3'], ['1968', '-25', '-15', '20', '-6', '-13', '-8', '-12', '-9', '-18', '10', '-3', '-13'], ['1969', '-11', '-14', '1', '18', '19', '5', '-2', '3', '9', '13', '13', '27'], ['1970', '9', '22', '8', '9', '-4', '-2', '-2', '-9', '11', '6', '2', '-12'], ['1971', '-2', '-20', '-17', '-8', '-5', '-19', '-11', '-3', '-4', '-6', '-5', '-9'], ['1972', '-24', '-17', '2', '0', '-4', '6', '1', '17', '2', '9', '4', '20'], ['1973', '29', '31', '27', '26', '26', '18', '10', '3', '10', '14', '6', '-6'], ['1974', '-15', '-28', '-5', '-11', '-2', '-6', '-4', '11', '-11', '-8', '-7', '-9'], ['1975', '7', '7', '13', '5', '16', '1', '-1', '-19', '-3', '-9', '-16', '-17'], ['1976', '-1', '-6', '-21', '-8', '-24', '-16', '-10', '-14', '-9', '-26', '-4', '10'], ['1977', '19', '22', '25', '28', '30', '24', '20', '16', '0', '2', '17', '2'], ['1978', '6', '14', '21', '15', '6', '-2', '3', '-17', '5', '0', '16', '10'], ['1979', '12', '-11', '18', '13', '5', '13', '2', '14', '25', '24', '28', '47'], ['1980', '30', '42', '30', '33', '36', '17', '28', '23', '19', '18', '29', '20'], ['1981', '55', '41', '49', '32', '24', '32', '34', '32', '17', '14', '24', '43'], ['1982', '10', '15', '-1', '10', '15', '5', '13', '7', '14', '13', '15', '43'], ['1983', '52', '41', '43', '31', '36', '20', '18', '33', '39', '16', '32', '17'], ['1984', '30', '17', '29', '8', '33', '5', '17', '16', '21', '16', '6', '-5'], ['1985', '22', '-6', '17', '11', '17', '18', '-1', '15', '15', '11', '8', '15'], ['1986', '28', '39', '27', '24', '24', '11', '11', '12', '0', '13', '11', '16'], ['1987', '36', '46', '16', '22', '25', '37', '45', '28', '39', '32', '25', '48'], ['1988', '58', '43', '51', '45', '43', '43', '34', '47', '41', '39', '12', '33'], ['1989', '15', '35', '36', '33', '16', '14', '34', '37', '37', '32', '20', '38'], ['1990', '41', '41', '77', '55', '46', '38', '43', '31', '29', '41', '46', '41'], ['1991', '41', '49', '35', '52', '38', '53', '48', '40', '48', '30', '31', '32'], ['1992', '44', '42', '48', '24', '32', '25', '12', '7', '0', '9', '3', '22'], ['1993', '37', '39', '36', '27', '27', '25', '28', '13', '10', '22', '6', '16'], ['1994', '27', '2', '27', '40', '28', '42', '30', '21', '29', '41', '46', '36'], ['1995', '51', '78', '45', '47', '26', '41', '48', '46', '32', '47', '45', '28'], ['1996', '25', '48', '32', '36', '27', '25', '35', '49', '25', '19', '41', '40'], ['1997', '31', '38', '53', '36', '36', '53', '35', '41', '53', '62', '65', '59'], ['1998', '60', '90', '63', '63', '69', '77', '68', '66', '42', '44', '49', '56'], ['1999', '48', '65', '34', '32', '31', '37', '37', '31', '41', '39', '38', '43'], ['2000', '23', '56', '57', '57', '36', '41', '38', '42', '40', '28', '32', '29'], ['2001', '42', '43', '55', '50', '56', '54', '60', '48', '53', '50', '69', '55'], ['2002', '75', '75', '89', '56', '63', '55', '61', '53', '62', '55', '58', '43'], ['2003', '73', '55', '57', '53', '60', '47', '53', '65', '64', '74', '52', '73'], ['2004', '58', '72', '64', '62', '38', '42', '24', '43', '50', '64', '70', '51'], ['2005', '72', '57', '69', '66', '62', '66', '63', '60', '74', '75', '71', '65'], ['2006', '56', '69', '62', '50', '46', '64', '52', '70', '61', '67', '70', '73'], ['2007', '95', '70', '69', '73', '66', '59', '60', '57', '59', '57', '54', '46'], ['2008', '23', '34', '73', '51', '47', '46', '59', '44', '62', '63', '64', '53'], ['2009', '61', '51', '52', '58', '64', '65', '69', '66', '68', '63', '76', '65'], ['2010', '73', '79', '91', '85', '73', '62', '59', '63', '59', '69', '77', '46'], ['2011', '48', '51', '62', '62', '51', '57', '71', '71', '54', '63', '56', '53'], ['2012', '45', '48', '56', '68', '75', '63', '53', '62', '72', '74', '73', '52'], ['2013', '67', '56', '65', '53', '58', '66', '57', '66', '78', '67', '78', '65'], ['2014', '73', '52', '76', '77', '85', '66', '56', '81', '88', '81', '66', '77'], ['2015', '81', '87', '90', '75', '75', '79', '71', '79', '82', '107', '103', '110'], ['2016', '115', '135', '131', '107', '91', '77', '82', '100', '88', '90', '91', '83'], ['2017', '98', '113', '113', '92', '89', '70', '82', '87', '76', '88', '86', '89'], ['2018', '77', '85', '91', '87', '81', '74', '78', '73', '76', '99', '78', '89']]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the problems of converting strings to number and also converting temperatures to Fahrenheit?

Comment: Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int

Comment: These aren't temperatures, but temperature **changes** in hundredth of °C. Except for the first element, which is a year.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty far along, I am not sure how you want to store/represent the temperatures once converted to Fahrenheit but maybe this piece of code helps:

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

link = "https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/tabledata_v3/GLB.Ts+dSST.txt"
f = requests.get(link)
data = f.text
lines = data.split('\n')


el = []                    # creates an empty list
for each in lines[8:159]:  # gets rid of unnecessary information. Prints from 1880 to 2018
    tempL = each.split()
    if (tempL and tempL[0] != 'Year'):    # gets rid of the excess data like the title
        el.append(tempL[:13])



###### What I added:

for temp_list in el:
    year = int(temp_list[0]) # the first elements seems to be the year
    
    for temp_Cel in temp_list[1:]: # all other elements are the temps
        temp_Far = int(temp_Cel) * (9 / 5) + 32 # int() converts the string to a integer
        print(temp_Far)
```