# How to scrape data like integer

Tags: python

I need this list deneme=['/n   1991','/n   1993','/n    2020']

pure_deneme=["1991","1993","2020"] like this list and all values must be integer. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats easy with list comprehensions:
if by '/n' you mean '\n' then you can simply do:

```
new_list = [int(element) for element in old_list]
```

if it is indeed '/n' you may have to do:

```
new_list = [int(element.replace('/n ', '')) for element in old_list]
```

This difference is because int() already knows how to ignore spaces and new lines ('\n'), but if there are other characters in there you will need to remove them with `.replace('whatever', '')`

Comment: Note that in case that the symbol is trailing (like here), you can use `strip` instead of `replace`: `int(element.strip('/n'))`

Comment: @motrix thanks it worked