# How to convert a string list to an int list?

Tags: python

I have this list

```
['456-789-154','741-562-785','457-154-129']
```

I want to convert it to int list like this:

```
[456,789,154,741,562,785,457,154,129]
```

Please help!!

I tried:

```
list = [item.replace("-",",") for item in list)
list = [item.replace("'","") for item in list)
```

But I don't know why the second line is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: @Gigioz That does not answer the question; the answers on that question do not split on a delimeter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a double list comprehension:

```py
l = ['456-789-154','741-562-785','457-154-129']
num_list = [int(y) for x in l for y in x.split("-")]
print(num_list) # [456, 789, 154, 741, 562, 785, 457, 154, 129]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach

```
my_list = ['456-789-154','741-562-785','457-154-129']
new_list = []
sub_list = []
for item in my_list:
    sub_list = item.split("-")
    for item in sub_list:
        new_list.append(int(item))


print(new_list)
```

Output

```
[456, 789, 154, 741, 562, 785, 457, 154, 129]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to return all stretches of digits, then [flatten the list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/967621) and convert to `int`:

```
import re
strs = ['456-789-154','741-562-785','457-154-129']
nums = [int(num) for sublist in (re.findall(r'\d+', s) for s in strs) for num in sublist]
print(nums)
# [456, 789, 154, 741, 562, 785, 457, 154, 129]
```