# Reason of TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' in python

Tags: python, types

```
A= [i for i in range(256)]

data = input()
dataList = list(data)
n=256
B = [i%len(dataList) for i in range(n)]
```

Through this code,

```
A = [0,1,2,....255]  
B = [0,1,2,3,0,1,...3] # this depends on the lenght of the input (here used 'toto' as input
```

I got the above result.

```
j=0
for i in range(255):
    j = (j+A[i]+B[i])%256
    B[i], B[j] = B[j], B[i]
```

However, when trying to do the above operation based on these two lists(A,B), TypeError: unsupported open type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' errors occured. I thought it was definitely an element type problem of A or B. So I also tried,

```
int_list = map(str, B)
```

but the problem still occurs.What I want is the "j = (j+S[i]+T[i])%256 operation" to work properly.

Comment: A = ['1','2',....'256']    is wrong shoul be A = [1,2,....256]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int Convert all strings in a list to int. are you using python 2 or python 3 ? please tag your question according to it

Comment: B = [dataList[i%len(dataList)] for i in range(n)] is wrong , should be  B = [i%len(dataList) for i in range(n)]

Comment: can we have : j=0
for i in range(255):
j = (j+S[i]+T[i])%256
S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i] translated to A, B (I believe S or T should be A or B but not sure)

Comment: @pippo1980 Checked all of your comments, and applied feedbacks. Thank you!

Comment: can you try to run the modified code again and see if it returns the same error ? which python are you using 2 or 3

Comment: @pippo1980 I'm using python3.7, and it doesn't show any error when I do as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mathematical calculations all the elements present must be integers/floats.
Modify this part:

```
for i in range(255):
    j = (j+int(A[i])+int(B[i]))%256
    B[i], B[j] = B[j], B[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate list `B`, you need to apply the `int` function to each character:

```py
data = input()
B = [int(data[i % len(data)]) for i in range(n)]
```

(btw: you don't say what `n` is, and `int_list = map(str, B)` is effectively the same as making a copy of `B`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I did what you intended to do ,

tried wit S = A and T = B;

using:

```
A= [i for i in range(256)]

data = input()
dataList = list(data)
n=256
B = [i%len(dataList) for i in range(n)]


print(A,'\n',B)

S = A

T = B

j=0
for i in range(255):
    j = (j+S[i]+T[i])%256
    S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]
    print(j)
```

and using : 'toto' as input I dont get any error

Comment: Mixed using of letter S,T,A,B was just my mistake. It was still object type problem. Thank you for editing this btw!