# Join multiple list elements into single list in python

Tags: python

I have following values stored in a string variable 'id'.

```
map00010
map00020
map00030
map00040
map00051
map00052
map00053
map00061
```

I would like to extract only the numerical values and store it in a list.

I am trying following line in my code:

```
print(id[3:].split())
```

But I am getting following output:

```
['00010']
['00020']
['00030']
['00040']
['00051']
['00052']
['00053']
['00061']
```

The expected output is:

list = [00010, 00020, 00030, 00040, 00051, 00052, 00053, 00061]

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: `print([i[3:] for i in id.split()])` use this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: Do you expect to keep this as strings, or as integers?  Because if you convert to integer, you'll get [10,20,30,40,51,52,53,61].  There are no leading zeros in an integer representation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
id = """map00010
map00020
map00030
map00040
map00051
map00052
map00053
map00061"""

lst = []
for item in id.split("\n"):
    lst.append(item[3:])

print(lst)
```

I don't know exactly how your string is formatted, but from your question, it seems as if they are separated by a `"\n"` newline character.

Answer (score 1):

if the above in question is a string you can create a list by

```
a = """map00010
map00020
map00030
map00040
map00051
map00052
map00053
map00061"""

lst = a.split()
```

once you have a list use a list comprehension and string slicing

```
lst2 = [item[3:] for item in lst]
print(lst2)
```

returns:

```
['00010', '00020', '00030', '00040', '00051', '00052', '00053', '00061']
```

Comment: user input a `string obj` not a list

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this code:**

```
id = '''map00010
map00020
map00030
map00040
map00051
map00052
map00053
map00061'''

print([i[3:] for i in id.split()])
```

**Output:**

```
['00010', '00020', '00030', '00040', '00051', '00052', '00053', '00061']
```

**METHOD-2: Using Regex**

```
import re
regobj = re.compile(r'\d+')

l = regobj.findall(id)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't clearly mentioned what your input variable is, if it's a string like:

```
string = "map00010 map00020 map00030 map00040 map00051 map00052 map00053 map00061"
```

you can use:

```
res = [x[3:] for x in string.split()]
print(res)
```

output:

```
['00010', '00020', '00030', '00040', '00051', '00052', '00053', '00061']
```