# How to call for information from a list?

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python and I would like some help. I'm currently trying to store information from the first line of a txt file in a tuple and I am having some trouble. The txt file's second line is:

Water: 0 0 4 2 1 3

I want to store the numbers only so my current code is:

```
water = []
with open(file_name) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    water_values = lines[1].strip()
    splitted = water_values.split(" ")
    splitted.remove("Water:")
    water.append(splitted)
```

However, when I call for water[1], expecting to receive 0, I find that the index is out of range and that the len(water) is only 1. When I print it, it says:

```
[['0', '0', '4', '2', '1', '3']]
```

How can I change it so that I can call for each element?

Comment: Did you mean `water_values = lines[0].strip()` ? Notice the `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: @AshokArora No, I believe lines[1] should be correct. That is the first line of the txt file.

Comment: @AnonymousUser Python, like many other programming languages start indexing at 0, so the 0 index, gives you the first item in a list (or a file). This gives the basic explanation with some additional tips and tricks: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-basics-of-indexing-and-slicing-python-lists-2d12c90a94cf

Answer (score 1):

When you call `water.append(splitted)` you are adding a new element to the end of the list and `splitted` is a list so you get a list of lists.

If you want to combine two lists, you should instead call `water += splitted`. The `+=` operator means that you are adding to the left side value, what ever is on the right side and is analogous to `water = water + splitted`.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thanks! But how do I change the elements in the list from string back into integers?

Comment: @AnonymousUser You can find lot of different ways here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.extend` rather than `.append`, i.e. instead of

```
water.append(splitted)
```

do

```
water.extend(splitted)
```

Simple example to show difference:

```
a = []
b = []
a.append([1,2,3])
b.extend([1,2,3])
print(a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you know to want more about handling `list`s in python read [More on Lists in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 1):

your code `water.append(splitted)` just adds `splitted` (which is a list) as a first element of `water` list. To add values from `splitted` you could just do following:
`water += splitted`
instead of
`water.append(splitted)`

Doing so - you will get `water = ['0', '0', '4', '2', '1', '3']`.

You can read more here [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)