# Create a dictionary using a string with numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which allows me to have a
dictionary like this :`{'Apple': 7,'Pearl: 5, 'strawberry': 3}` 
using this string:  `"Apple,2,5;Pearl,3,2;Strawberry,1,2;"`.

I want to use the numbers on the string as an integer and do the addition process to be the result. However I was trying to split the string into pieces so I can make it an integer

```
   def cal(Fruitsamount):
        Fruitsamount.split(";")
        dict1 = {Fruitsamount[0:5]: Fruitsamount[5:8]}
        return dict1
    print(cal("Apple,2,5;Pearl,3,2;Strawberry,1,2;"))
```

I would like to know how can I transform part of the numbers on the string into integers so I can do the addition process

Comment: Convert str to int with `int(str)`. So `int("123")` creates a int with a value of `123`

Comment: Split each part again by `,`, get `[1:]` to get the list of ints, then [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7368789/2745495)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first split the text on `;` which will give the key and values for each item for the dictionary, and then split these values on `,`, the first value is the key, and rests are the values for the given key, iterate through each values and type cast the values to the integer, finally calculate the `sum` of these values. But since your sample string contains `;` at the end, you may want to `strip` it first before proceeding.

```py
def getDict(text):
    result = {}
    text = text.strip(';')
    for row in text.split(';'):
        cols = row.split(',')
        result[cols[0]] = sum(int(i) for i in cols[1:])
    return result

getDict('Apple,2,5;Pearl,3,2;Strawberry,1,2;')
#output: {'Apple': 7, 'Pearl': 5, 'Strawberry': 3}
```

One-liner solution using `lambda`, `map`, and comprehension:

```py
getDict = lambda text: {col[0]:sum(map(int, col[1:])) 
                        for col in map(lambda x: x.split(','), 
                                       (row for row in text.strip(';').split(';')))
                        }
getDict('Apple,2,5;Pearl,3,2;Strawberry,1,2;')
# ooutput: {'Apple': 7, 'Pearl': 5, 'Strawberry': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the result of the split by `;`. Then, you can construct the dictionary by unpacking the split by `,` and summing over the numbers.

```
def cal(Fruitsamount):
    d = {}
    for item in Fruitsamount.strip(";").split(";"):
        k, *vs = item.split(",")
        d[k] = sum(map(int, vs))
    return d

print(cal("Apple,2,5;Pearl,3,2;Strawberry,1,2;"))
{'Apple': 7, 'Pearl': 5, 'Strawberry': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform them to integers using `int`.

```py
def to_dict(inventory):
    items = inventory.split(";")
    items = [item.split(',') for item in items]
    keys = [item[0] for item in items]
    values = [sum(map(int, item[1:])) for item in items]
    return dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to re-implement the code to make it easier to read, after you split by ";" and get each key-value pair you have to split by comma and get first element as key, all of the rest value as values. Here is my implementation:

```
x = "Apple,2,5;Pearl,3,2;Strawberry,1,2;"


def cal(string):
  dict_keys = string.split(';')

  result_dict = dict()
  for element in dict_keys:
    key_value = element.split(',')
    key = key_value[0]
    result_dict[key] = [int(val) for val in list(key_value[1:])]

 
  return result_dict


print(cal("Apple,2,5;Pearl,3,2;Strawberry,1,2;"))
```

Simply use int() to every value in a list could do the work.

Comment: It's never a good idea to add your answer as image, please edit the answer and add the solution as text, you can format the code in the answer

Comment: Thank you, I just made an mistake. I've edited as code.