# Changing elements of list from str to int?

Tags: python, list

```
m1 = [[['64,56'], ['77,9'], ['3,55,44,22,11']]]
m2 = [[[64, 56], [77, 9], [3, 55, 44, 22, 11]]]
```

How do I go from "m1" to "m2"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: you can refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int

Answer (score 1):

You can use (nested) list comprehension with `split`:

```py
lst = ['7', '4,9', '9,7', '5,44,9,8']

output = [int(num) for item in lst for num in item.split(',')]
print(output) # [7, 4, 9, 9, 7, 5, 44, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine elements into one string using `join()`, then `split()` and convert to int using `map()`

```
list(map(int,','.join(lst).split(',')))
```

Comment: Ooh this is clever.