# convert Element of list value in Dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, data-structures

I have a data like that

```
[{'point1': ['20.900', '15.300', '20.400'], 
  'point2': ['0.600', '34.700', '8.100'], 
  'point3': ['12.100', '15.800', '2.300'], 
  'point4': ['15.000', '5.800', '16.900']}]
```

How can I convert the numbers into integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in one line:

```
l = [{'point1': ['20.900', '15.300', '20.400'], 'point2': ['0.600', '34.700', '8.100'], 'point3': ['12.100', '15.800', '2.300'], 'point4': ['15.000', '5.800', '16.900']}]

result = [{k: [int(float(i)) for i in v] for k, v in l[0].items()}]
```

The result will be:

```
[{'point1': [20, 15, 20],
  'point2': [0, 34, 8],
  'point3': [12, 15, 2],
  'point4': [15, 5, 16]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop:

```
for d in lst:
    for v in d.values():
        for i, num in enumerate(v):
            v[i] = int(float(num))

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'point1': [20, 15, 20],
  'point2': [0, 34, 8],
  'point3': [12, 15, 2],
  'point4': [15, 5, 16]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int) asked already check that too!
you can do this also:

```py
arr = [{
    'point1': ['20.900', '15.300', '20.400'], 
    'point2': ['0.600', '34.700', '8.100'], 
    'point3': ['12.100', '15.800', '2.300'], 
    'point4': ['15.000', '5.800', '16.900'],
    }]

[{k : list(map(float, v))  for k, v in point.items() } for point in arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array=[{'point1': ['20.900', '15.300', '20.400'], 'point2': ['0.600', '34.700', '8.100'], 'point3': ['12.100', '15.800', '2.300'], 'point4': ['15.000', '5.800', '16.900']}]
new_array=array[0]

for i in new_array.values():
    k=0
    for j in i:
        i[k]=int(float(j))
        k=k+1
        
print(new_array)
```