# How can I convert a list of strings within a dictionary's values to int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a Python dictionary with keys that are strings, and values that are lists of numbers which are also strings. I'd like to convert the numbers to int, but am having some trouble. Just to illustrate, I'd like to change:

```
d = {'a': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['4', '5', '6'], 'c': ['7', '8', '9']}
```

into

```
d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}
```

Comment: You do it the same as any other list. Except in this case the list is named `d[key]` where `key` is a key in your dictionary instead of e.g. `my_list`. What trouble are you having?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int)

Comment: So I do: 

for key, value in d:
   int(value)

but then it says there are too many items to unpack. 
If I just do int(key) it tries to turn the alphabetical characters to ints which isn't what I want and wouldn't work anyways.

Comment: Then you want to ask [how to iterate over keys and values of a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/843953). Note that you can't just convert the strings to ints, you have to _assign those ints back!_.

Comment: This is why it is good to show your attempt: it helps us help you diagnose your actual issue. Please see [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and how to provide a [mre].

Comment: Rather than being unclear, this should be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75666408/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have commented this out but unfortunately, I am new to Stack Overflow and don't have enough reputation. But based on [@pranav-hosangadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pranav-hosangadi) suggestion you can just do it in a single line.

```
d = {key: list(map(int, value)) for key, value in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
for key in d.keys():
    d[key] = list(map(int, d[key]))
```